# Translate curl command to python requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests, pagerduty

I have the following curl command which I can use to retrieve a list of users from a specific group in PagerDuty:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2" -H "Authorization: Token token=xxx" -X GET --data-urlencode "team_ids[]=abc" 'https://api.pagerduty.com/users'
```

How can I translate this exact command to run in a python get.requests() command? I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I'm currently trying but it doesn't filter on the group:

```
response = requests.get(
        'https://api.pagerduty.com/users', params = {"data-urlencode": "team_ids[]=abc"}, headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2','Authorization': 'Token token=xxx'}
    )

    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you concatenating the URL with the string "0" in your python get request? For one, you can just restate it as `str(0)` instead of `str(int(0))` and you don't seem to be using an offset param in your curl command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply omit **`--data-urlencode`** from your params:

```
import requests

params = {
    'team_ids[]':"abc",
    "offset": '0',
}
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
    'Authorization': 'Token token=xxx',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.pagerduty.com/users', params=params, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

if first solution is hard for you u can use one of websites that convert curl command to pytho/php etc ... code

[curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/)

https://sqqihao.github.io/trillworks.html

https://www.scrapingbee.com/curl-converter/python/